# NoClassDefFoundError when using a class from a jar file

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, maven

I am trying to get a search web application running and needs to use another Java project to do all the backend operations.  I exported the project into a jar file and added it to my dynamic webapp project.  The first thing I tried was "Add External jars" from Properties > Java Build Path.  This didn't work so I also tried adding the jar in WEB-INF/lib which also did not work.  How do I correctly add the jar file so I can use that project in my webapp?

More specifically this the error I get:

```
message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
```

root cause

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/accumulo/core/client/Instance
com.afspq.model.Results.getResults(Results.java:46)
com.afspq.web.ProcessQuery.doGet(ProcessQuery.java:31)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.accumulo.core.client.Instance
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
com.afspq.model.Results.getResults(Results.java:46)
com.afspq.web.ProcessQuery.doGet(ProcessQuery.java:31)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 logs.

Comment: Is this only giving you runtime errors?

Comment: Yes, this is a runtime error.  Also, in the "Problems" tab it there is a message that says:  `Classpath entry path/to/my/jar will not be exported or published.  Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.`

Comment: did you remove the jar from your build path after adding it to the lib folder?

Comment: @user1454749 Yes, I removed from the build path after adding it to the lib folder.

Comment: @BlackVegetable I am using Eclipse 3.7.2 with Tomcat.

Comment: What JARs exactly do you have placed in `/WEB-INF/lib` then?

Comment: @BalusC I only place one jar file (search.jar) which is from the project I am trying to use in my webapp.  That project has a whole bunch of Maven dependencies so I'm thinking if I need to add those as well.  If so how do I add the Maven dependencies to the WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: Just copy them into `/WEB-INF/lib` as well or just install and use Maven instead.

Comment: @BalusC Well, my webapp project is also a maven project.  I've updated the dependencies and don't have any warnings or anything.  But when comes time to call the method in the Search class I still get the same error.

Comment: Apparently the dependency is not properly built in to the WAR. Perhaps you've set it to `provided` or something for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was sort of a painful process but I had to manually add all the jar files from Accumulo, Hadoop and Zookeeper.  I had to add the jar files to two locations.  One was the build path (Right click Web project > Properties > Java Build Path > Add external jars), and the other was the WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder in my Web project.  This fixed it for me.  For some reason Maven was not adding the dependencies although they were all specified in my pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following to your Maven pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.accumulo</groupId>
    <artifactId>accumulo-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and NOT adding it within Eclipse. The pom.xml is the truth not Eclipse.

To check everything is right go on command line:

```
mvn clean package
```

deploy the created war into tomcat to make sure everything is ok.

Comment: Unfortunately the stack trace says something different. Without your pom its hard!